# How to change default host in mysql command?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to show grant for a particular user, so I typed like this.

```
mysql> show grants for username@localhost;
```

But normally I only use mysql in localhost. How can I set default host name so that I can use like this expression?

```
mysql> show grants for username;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that. Since [SHOW GRANTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) relies on [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) syntax itself, it will use rules for user naming, that are defined by MySQL - and it clearly defines that if you're not specifying `hostname` part for user in your `GRANT` statement - it will be treated as `%` and no other way:

> **Account Names and Passwords**
>
> The user value indicates the MySQL account to which the [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)
>   statement applies. To accommodate granting rights to users from
>   arbitrary hosts, MySQL supports specifying the user value in the form
>   user_name@host_name. If a user_name or host_name value is legal as an
>   unquoted identifier, you need not quote it. However, quotation marks
>   are necessary to specify a user_name string containing special
>   characters (such as “-”), or a host_name string containing special
>   characters or wildcard characters (such as “%”); for example,
>   'test-user'@'%.com'. Quote the user name and host name separately.
>
> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example,
>   user_name@'%.example.com' applies to user_name for any host in the
>   example.com domain, and user_name@'192.168.1.%' applies to user_name
>   for any host in the 192.168.1 class C subnet.

and:

> The simple form **user_name** is a synonym for user_name@'%'.

(from the corresponding manual page). To be more specific about naming rules - see this [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html) (there you'll find same answer about non-specified *hostname* when defining account name)